# radioactive decay in molecular constituents

Tags: radioactivity, radiation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What happens to chemical compunds that include radioactive nuclei, when those decay?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/8081/what-happens-to-chemical-compunds-that-include-radioactive-nuclei-when-those-dec)

Suppose a radioactive atom, which is incorporated in a molecule, decays? What becomes of the bonds? Are there instances in which those bonds affect the decay, either with regard to the half-life, or the action of the decay? Are the resultant products, for example, slowed by the bonds?

Comment: I asked a similar question some time ago: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/8081/what-happens-to-chemical-compunds-that-include-radioactive-nuclei-when-those-dec

Comment: So you did, cheers. Feel free to close, any passing mods.

Comment: Also of interest: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/56417/nuclear-fission-and-half-life