# Does KI have to be a salt of stable I-127 isotope?

Tags: radioactivity, isotopes

I was recently watching a TV show where some people exposed to radiation were asked to take KI. I googled for the information and discovered [this](http://www.bt.cdc.gov/radiation/ki.asp) and also the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potassium_iodide).

From what I read, I understand that KI is a salt of stable Iodine. Why does this have to be so? Can there be KI with I-131 isotope? Or is the therapeutic KI salt used to treat radiation poisoning specifically enriched to have I-127 isotope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can [do chemistry with unstable isotopes](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/8081/what-happens-to-chemical-compunds-that-include-radioactive-nuclei-when-those-de). But in the case of [I-131](http://ie.lbl.gov/education/parent/I_iso.htm), the halflife of only 8 days implies that if you have stored the salts for length of time the remaining activity will be very small.

Nor do you find any radioactive iodine in environmental iodine except in the neighborhood of recent radioactive events of various kinds.